# Heroku: deploy app with which uses ocrmypdf

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, ocrmypdf

I need to deploy my nodejs web server which uses ocrmypdf. I choose heroku. Currently i use such heroku buildpacks:

```
1. heroku/python
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
3. https://github.com/pathwaysmedical/heroku-buildpack-tesseract
4. heroku/nodejs
```

Tesseract works perfectly but not ocrmypdf.
My requirenments.txt has only ocrmypdf==13

```
$ ocrmypdf l.pdf l2.pdf
Opened a file
Opened a file                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Opened a file                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Opened a file                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Opened a file                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Opened a file                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Opened a file                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Scanning contents: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
20/20 [00:00<00:00, 381.51page/s]
Start processing 8 pages concurrently
Opened a file
    1 [tesseract] read_params_file: Can't open pdf                                                                                                                                                                                       
    1 [tesseract] read_params_file: Can't open txt                                                                                                                                                                                       
    1 [tesseract] Warning: Invalid resolution 25 dpi. Using 70 instead.                                                                                                                                                                  
    1 [tesseract] Estimating resolution as 418                                                                                                                                                                                           
    3 [tesseract] read_params_file: Can't open pdf                                                                                                                                                                                       
    3 [tesseract] read_params_file: Can't open txt                                                                                                                                                                                       
    3 [tesseract] Warning: Invalid resolution 25 dpi. Using 70 instead.                                                                                                                                                                  
    3 [tesseract] Estimating resolution as 215                                                                                                                                                                                           
    2 [tesseract] read_params_file: Can't open pdf                                                                                                                                                                                       
    2 [tesseract] read_params_file: Can't open txt                                                                                                                                                                                       
    2 [tesseract] Warning: Invalid resolution 25 dpi. Using 70 instead.                                                                                                                                                                  
    2 [tesseract] Estimating resolution as 236                                                                                                                                                                                           
    4 [tesseract] read_params_file: Can't open pdf                                                                                                                                                                                       
    4 [tesseract] read_params_file: Can't open txt                                                                                                                                                                                       
    4 [tesseract] Warning: Invalid resolution 25 dpi. Using 70 instead.                                                                                                                                                                  
    4 [tesseract] Estimating resolution as 224                                                                                                                                                                                           
    4 [tesseract] contains_unichar_id(unichar_id):Error:Assert failed:in file ../../src/ccutil/unicharset.h, line 509                                                                                                                    
    6 [tesseract] read_params_file: Can't open pdf                                                                                                                                                                                       
    6 [tesseract] read_params_file: Can't open txt                                                                                                                                                                                       
    6 [tesseract] Warning: Invalid resolution 25 dpi. Using 70 instead.                                                                                                                                                                  
    6 [tesseract] Estimating resolution as 199                                                                                                                                                                                           
OCR:  20%|█████████████████████████████████████▏                                                                                                                                                    | 4.0/20.0 [00:05<00:20,  1.30s/page]
SubprocessOutputError
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?